# Easy way to bypass cache in Drupal when visit certain URL

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-cache

Mainly when synchronizing via HTTP, the data must not be from cache. Is there a way, like query parameter in URL to bypass cache of any kind in Drupal.

Something like `request-url?cache=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out "Cache exclude" module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude

Or if you want to do it from code you can add following line at top of specific pages:

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE;
```